# UI Automator TestProject.jar location on the device

Tags: java, android, jar, android-uiautomator

I am using UIAutomator to perform UI Automation testing on Android devices. My question is, can the jar file (say TestProject.jar) reside in the device in a location other than /data/local/tmp?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the relative path of `.jar` file:

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest <path to TestProject.jar> -c package.class
```

If we don't provide a relative path, framework searches for `.jar` file in `/data/local/tmp` by default